# Angular.js error causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to setup a simple Angular.js app however it seems to be causing an infnite loop and I'm not sure why. My guess is it's a simple stupid mistake.  Any help would be much appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is execute show() on page load.  Basically a search that shows all info.  They user can enter text and this will filter the results again on show.  My issues seems to be in the routing.

http://jsfiddle.net/qk2w31c4/

```
/* This is the controller */

var sigM = angular.module('sigM', ['ngRoute', 'ngGrid', 'ui.date']);

sigM.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/setup', {
        template : ' ',
        controller : 'sigSetupCtrl'
    }).when('/result/:params/', {
        template : 'sigID',
        controller : 'sigSearchResultCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/setup'
    });
} ]);

sigM.controller('sigSearchCntl', function($scope,$log,$http,$q, $window) {
    $scope.setup = { hid: ''};  

    $scope.show = function() {
        window.location = '#/result/' + angular.toJson($scope.setup);
    };
});

sigM.controller('sigSetupCtrl', function($scope,$log,$http,$q) {
    $scope.setup = { hid: ''};  
    $scope.show();
});


sigM.controller('sigSearchResultCtrl', function($scope,$log,$http,$q,$routeParams, $window) {
    $log.info("----------: " + angular.toJson($routeParams));
    //my code

});


<body ng-controller="sigSearchCntl">

  <form ng-submit="show()">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Search</td> <td> <input ng-model="setup.hid"></td><td><input type="submit" value="Show"></td></tr>

    </table>
  </form>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="sigID" >
        <div ng-show="loading" style='clear:both; text-align: center;'>Loading report...<img src="Wait3.gif"></div>

        <div ng-show="!loading" style='margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px; '><h3> Sig: {{hid}} </h3></div>
        <div ng-show="!loading" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: fyi don't use window directly. use the location service.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Why are you injecting services you don't use?

Comment: @mortsahl I use those within my code (//my code).  When I remove all my code, I still get the same errors. For ease, I removed that part.

Comment: What is happening that you conclude there is an infinite loop? Care to share the error message(s) you are getting? ;)